# Why is JMeter showing an undefined variable error in the response body even if the web page is working properly if I run it manually?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

(1/1)

ErrorException

Undefined index: current_institute_id

I am getting above error in jmeter response body but its working fine if i run web page manually . Also i have passed the value of current institute in request.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3YGA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNdUk.png)

```
        <div class="container">
                                <div class="trace trace-as-html">
                    <table class="trace-details">
                        <thead class="trace-head"><tr><th>
                            <h3 class="trace-class">
                                <span class="text-muted">(1/1)</span>
                                <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="ErrorException">ErrorException</abbr></span>
                            </h3>
                            <p class="break-long-words trace-message">Undefined index: current_institute_id</p>
                        </th></tr></thead>
                        <tbody><tr><td><span class="block trace-file-path">in <span title="/var/www/html/mycc/t11/app/Http/Controllers/inquiry/AdmissionFormController.php line 1666"><strong>AdmissionFormController.
```

Comment: Please share the output of sampler in listener. And screenshot of the screen where you are able to see the error.

Comment: @AbhishekPuri  I have added screenshot . now you can see the error.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. Can you share the screenshot of three more things

1. Sampler Result
2. Request Headers
3. Response Data -- Response Headers

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the Screenshot the information provided is not enough to completely investigate the issue. But I can notice that the data you are sending is not recognized by the server. This means you may be sending data that the server was not expecting.

The solution is to record the script manually after understanding the flow.
Found a video explaining the process. Maybe it'll help you understand the way how you can record manually and not depend on tools that ultimately misguide you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=10&v=Njjz1kzS24E

I'm not sure that'll help with the information provided by you. But it may lead you to a solution